# Чёрный экран в эмуляторе андроида

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, эмулятор

Когда я запускаю андроид программу в стандартном эмуляторе xamarin
Появляется черный экран.
Показывает что, ваш пк не поддерживает Intel.
Как решить?

Comment: покажите скриншоты sdk manager. что за эмулятор стоит и какие дополнительные ракеты установлены.

Comment: уже поздно,надо было раньше